# Add word to end of line in Ansible

Tags: linux, ansible, debian

I've been trying a lot of lineinfile and replace examples but i can't get it to work.

I have the following lines:

```
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian buster main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
```

And i want them to look like this:

```
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian buster main contrib
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib
```

I tried to do so with Ansible;

```
- name: Add contrib repository
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/apt/sources.list
    backup: yes
    state: present
    regexp: '^(deb (.*)$)'
    backrefs: yes
    line: '\1 contrib'
  check_mode: no
```

Which kinda works, but after the 2nd run it shows like, e.g.

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib contrib
```

So it keeps adding the word with every run.

Obviously the lines are not as-is on every system, but they do start with deb or deb-src

Thanks!

Comment: `lineinfile: This is primarily useful when you want to change a single line in a file only.` Try using `replace` module

Answer (score -1):

```
- name: Add contrib repository
  replace:
    dest: /etc/apt/sources.list
    regexp: '^(deb.+)(?<! contrib)$'
    replace: '\1 contrib'
```

Comment: does not check tho if the word contrib is elswhere on the line

Answer (score -1):

`lineinfile` only replaces 1 single line. `replace` changes **all** lines that match.

```yaml
- name: Add contrib repository
  replace:
    dest: /etc/apt/sources.list
    regexp: '^(deb(?!.* contrib).*)'
    replace: '\1 contrib'
```

Note that a negative lookahead regular expression like `(?!bar)` means: *"assert that 'bar' does not **immediately** follow as the next word"* and **not**: *"assert that 'bar' is not somewhere in the rest of the line"*. Note also the greediness of `.*`.

This Ansible code snippet can be used to add any option / string to all lines that does not yet have that option / string.